# Configuring Nexus 3 (3.0m7) to run as a Linux Service

Tags: nexus

Can anyone help me translate the instructions for setting this up as a Linux Service (at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#service-linux) into English?

After following them as best I could, I get the following when starting the service:

```
su: user / does not exist
```

Here are the parts of the instructions which were unclear:

> In the bin/nexus script remove the line below.
>
> INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX="su - $run_as_user -c"

The line in the file is actually

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX=""
```

but ok, I can remove that.  However, the next instruction is:

> Replace the entire link with this line:
>
> exec su - $run_as_user "$prg_dir/$progname" $@

What is meant by "the entire link"?  The thing I removed above?  That was the first line in the file - therefore the three variables above have not yet been set.... and is probably the reason the script currently fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get the book fixed, it shouldn't have this in it anymore.

Download the 3.0 release, this was just a bug in 3.0m7, and it has been fixed. You don't need to make these changes.

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217965118

The only things you need to do is edit $NEXUS_HOME/bin/nexus.rc, uncomment the  run_as_user line, and set the value for it appropriately.  Then just symlink $NEXUS_HOME/bin/nexus to /etc/init.d/nexus, and after that run chkconfig or update-rc.d depending on your Linux version.

Comment: I did uncomment `run_as_user` and set the user. I also symlinked `$NEXUS_HOME/bin/nexus` to `/etc/init.d/nexus`. But after a reboot Nexus is not started. AFAIK `nexus` script needs a command line option like `start` or `run`. Could that be the problem? Is there any way to pass the option? Or is that not neccessary?